# how to count distribution between all categorical labels and store total occurrence in list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataset where i have total 6 types of labels, `label_1`, `label_2`, `label_3`, `label_4`,`label_5`,`label_6`. and an extra one that i created for if none of the events occurring,if certain event occurs the value of label shows 1,I want to calculate distribution between these labels.

**my dataframe:**

| label_1 | label_2 | label_3 | labe_4 | label_5 | label_6 | none |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

**output I want:**

```
# these values i calculated individually.  
balance_counts = [15294,1595,8449,478,7877,1405,143346]
```

Comment: just sum each column? `df.sum(axis=0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
balance_counts = df.sum().tolist()
```

to get the column sums into a list.